# Exception using CruiseControl .NET (particular build project failing)

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have recently taken control of maintaining our continuous integration system which provides installers (mostly for projects built using Visual Studio and the .NET Framework).

This uses CruiseControl.NET server side and CCTray client side so developers can 'fire' new builds of software when work has been completed. Source control is provided by Sourcegear Vault.

One of the build projects has started failing in the last few days with the following error as soon as you force a build via CCTray:

System.Exception: There is no version 0 of $/xxx/yyy in [repositoryName]. at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.FortressClient.GetVersion(String repositoryFolderPath, String workingDir, Int64 folderVersion) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.FortressVaultSourceControl.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.MultiSourceControl.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)

I have checked ccnet.config and the build script for this project but everything seems correct.

Does anyone have any clues? There have been no upgrades to anything on the development server as far as I am aware.

Comment: I've only found this : http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13460. Maybe you should ask the Sourcegear Vault support. And also check if SV was upgraded at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

We've just had the same problem. I don't know how we ran into it exactly, but we had killed ccnetservice before.

However I found out that the file ProjectName.fortressState was missing. I recreated that file from another project, renamed it to "ProjectName.fortressState", modified the content and restartet ccnetservice.

After that the project worked again on ccnet.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem here for a few projects. None of the previously suggested solutions have resolved it and Vault support is non-responsive in their forum:(

The only workaround Ive found so far is to create a project that builds this (whatever) with a new project name.